# What do I have to set to hide the Tennant ID field in the login?

Tags: moqui

I do not use multitenancy right now. I noticed a condition `ec.getWeb().getSession().getAttribute("moqui.tenantAllowOverride")! != "N"` in the login.ftl. But I have not managed to set it, so that my users do not see the Tennant ID field.

Answer (score 0):

The moqui.tenantAllowOverride session attribute is set by the framework from the TenantHostDefault.allowOverride field is there is a record for the hostname of the current request. You could set this manually (in pre-actions) or just comment out the field in the login form. Either approach requires small changes to files in the runtime directory. At some point there may be a flag in the Moqui Conf XML file to disable multi-tenant features completely, but there is nothing for that now.